# Hexadecimal byte string conversion to unicode in python

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, byte

I read a string from a text file which contains many special characters in 'rb' mode and store it in a variable. But when I insert it into a textbox in tkinter some characters go missing.

```
inp = tut.encrypt_text(tut.getKey(password.get()),text.get("1.0", END))
```

The code passes a string to the encrypting function to encrypt the text and then gets the encrypted text in hex byte string.

```
outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))
```

this code is used for writing the encrypted text to a file and then the same is being read from the file and returned back to the call made above.

```
with open(outputFile, 'rb') as out:
    output =out.read()
return output
```

The encrypted text in file is:

```
0000000000000011P”=êäS£¾1:–ø{pâRÆA<,ã É˜“Uê
```

Here itself some characters are missing. When i read it in 'rb' mode and store in variable output and return to the call made, the variable has the value

```
b'0000000000000011P\x94=\xea\xe4S\x0f\xa3\xbe1\x18:\x96\xf8{p\xe2R\xc6A<,\xe3\xa0\xc9\x8d\x98\x93\x04\x08U\xea'
```

But when I insert it in the textbox using the code

```
text.delete('1.0', END)
text.insert(END, inp)
```

The text that is being printed in the textbox is

```
0000000000000011P=êäS£¾1:ø{pâRÆA<,ã ÉUê.
```

This text is different from the one which was in the file. How can I get the same string which is in the text file in the textbox?